# How secure is to use scp with GitHub actions?

Tags: security, github, github-actions, scp

Right now I use [scp-action](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action) to copy some files to one server.

How secure is this method?

What are the alternatives to using GitHub Actions, I was thinking of running a custom action of `scp` and setting up a local runner on my side.

Answer (score 0):

One other alternative is to configure a bare repository on your server, and adding it as a second remote on your local repository.
Now every time you want to deploy code to your server, you push to this remote. You then create a git hook on your server that fires post-push, and automatically executes a script that restarts a service, for example.
Read more [here](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-git-repo-to-server/)

For me, I am having a hard time choosing between these two alternatives because I have some unanswered questions :

- for github actions, how secure is the SSH key being ran from a github runner ? and given that my codebase is huge, isn't it a bit overkill to scp all my files after a hotfix commit where I changed only 1 or 2 files ?
- for git bare repo: would the size of the git folder be a problem ? and how to secure my server so it would not serve the .git folder ?

Answer (score -1):

Your approach of using scp can be secure, but there are some considerations to keep in mind:

- **SSH key handling**: Ensure that you are storing your SSH private key and any other sensitive data as GitHub secrets and not
  hard-coding them in your workflow file.
- **Key Management**: Use a dedicated SSH key pair specifically for this GitHub Action.
- **Least Privilege Principle**: The SSH account used for copying should have the minimum necessary permissions. It should only be able
  to write to the required directories.
- **Auditing & Logging**: Ensure that both GitHub Actions and your server have proper auditing and logging enabled.

Your approach of using a self-hosted runner has security advantages over GitHub hosted runners as you would have control over the self-hosted runner. You can setup ingress filtering on the SSH port with ease with self-hosted runners. Also, you can use private server endpoint for SSH and potentially eliminate the internet exposure for your server.